# How to loop a public method on ASP.NET C# using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have the following method:

```
//BOLO stands for Be On The Lookout
[WebMethod]
public void LoadBolos()
{
    List<string> bolos;

    //If not loaded before
    if (ViewState["bolos"] == null)
    {
        List<string> bolos = GetBolos();

        ViewState["bolos"] = bolos;
        ViewState["index"] = 0;
    }

    else
    {
        bolos = (List<string>)ViewState["bolos"];
    }

    int index = ViewState["index"] != null ? (int)ViewState["index"] : 0;

    if (bolos.Count > 0)
    {
        imgBolo.ImageUrl = bolos[index];
        index++;
        index = index >= bolos.Count ? 0 : index;
    }

    ViewState["index"] = index;
}
```

And here is the js file on the aspx

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    BoloTimer();
}

function BoloTimer()
{
    BoloSwitch();

    boloTimer = setTimeout
    (
        function ()
        {
            boloTimer = null;
            BoloTimer();
        }, 

        10000
    );
}

function BoloSwitch()
{
    $.ajax
    (
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'NameOfPage.aspx/LoadBolos"',
            data: '{ }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:
            function (msg)
            {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I need to loop this method every 10 seconds, so I can refresh an image on the aspx page.

However, even though I put some breakpoints on the js and the cs, it does execute the function, but it never reaches the webmethod.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you watching for errors in browser console?

Comment: `"it does execute the function, but it never reaches the webmethod"` - Then where specifically does it fail?  Any errors on the JavaScript console?  Is `BoloSwitch()` invoked?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: That is the weird part, no errors on the console, if I place a breakpoint on BoloSwitch, it does reach it. If I go to Network, it states that Post with a Result of 500 was made. But no update is seen on screen nor the breakpoint on LoadBolos on the cs is hit.